# Why does this system of equations take so long to solve? Is there any way to speed it up?

Tags: equation-solving

I wish my math was sophisticated enough to give this question a better title.

I'm tying to solve the voltage drop in a long wire, where every `d` distance, there is a device drawing power `pow`. `pow` is a constant. I came up with a set of equations for four devices, but when I do the calculations with 7 or more devices the calculations take so long I can't wait for them to finish. Ultimately I'd like to do the calculations for over 100 devices.

`c1` is a constant that I've been using to simplify things, and I've just been setting it to a value of `1` for now.

```
v4==v3-i4*c1
v3==v2-i3*c1
v2==v1-i2*c1
v1==v0-i1*c1
v0==100000

i4==pow/v4
i3==i4+pow/v3
i2==i3+pow/v2
i1==i2+pow/v1
```

I'm not sure why, but `Solve[allEquations,v4,PositiveReals]` fails. If I use `Reduce`, it gives values for v1 through v4. I can also use `Eliminate` and eliminate all variables other than `v4`, but that takes really long even for just these 9 equations. But if I add more equations, eventually it would go up to `v100`, it takes way too long to finish.

Is there any way to make this solvable faster? I have the feeling that even if I ran it for a few days straight I wouldn't get a solution.

Comment: Not directly on topic, but the equations you've written down don't make a lot of sense given how [the laws of physics apply to electric circuits.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws)  Specifically, the first set of equations would make sense if all of your devices were in series in the circuit;  but if that's the case, then the current through all of the devices should be the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly all the code that you are using. Check it by scrape-n-pasting it from your post into a new fresh empty notebook and confirm that it shows exactly the problem you are describing. That way someone else should be able to exactly reproduce what you are doing. Thanks

Comment: Reduce returns `c1 i4 + v4 == v3`, which is the input equation for `v4`.  Is this a useful solution?